Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
I'm experiencing a critical issue with my Ubuntu system and need some assistance. When I attempt to boot my system, I'm confronted with the following error message:

Potential solution attempted:
I've already tried various troubleshooting steps like checking the boot order in the BIOS, and updating GRUB without success.

I see an inability to mount root due to unknown block... so I'll suggest checking your drive health (ie. using your hardware's SMART capabilities from live media), RAM test & ensure you have valid hardware first.. If your drive is still good, then you can perform file-system checks (but I'd avoid making changes to system until you know hardware is good, as if you have a failing disk you want to preserve whatever health remains for data recovery if needed)

This question is similar to: Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
